# Вычислить размер строки с помощью python-docx

Tags: python

Есть текст в **Word**. Нужно расставить переносы строки в **Word** в соответствии с определенными алгоритмами. Для этого, зная шрифт, мне необходимо посчитать где строка заканчиваться.
В **python-docx** такой опции не нашел, я так понял, что он вообще не воспринимает строку как какую-то отдельную сущность. У него есть **paragraphs** и **runs**.
Может есть такая опция в **python-docx**? Или может эту проблему можно решить другими способами в **Python**?

Comment: Вы под Windows работаете в Word, используя Python для раставления переносов слов? Есть встроенный функционал у самого Word (был с версии 2000)

Comment: Да, под Windows. Там есть встроенный функционал для ручной перестановки, а мне нужно, чтобы в большом тексте (более 100 страниц) автоматически расставлялись переносы строки по заданному мной алгоритму (который будет периодически меняться). А моя главная проблема на сегодня, что я не могу посчитать где заканчивается строка.

Comment: Т.е. размер строки зависит от 1) шрифта (в т.ч. обычный он, жирный или курсив) 2) размера (12пт, 14пт..). Т.е. мне нужно, зная шрифт и ширину листа понять на каком символе будет перенос. А потом уже я буду подставлять свои алгоритмы, корректируя эти переносы.

Comment: документацию уже смотрели?https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Да, смотрел, но не нашел этого